# Replace string to translate works only with the first word in Python

Tags: python

I have a loop where I try to find months to translate them in french. It worked, but when I have two months in the same string, only the first is translated.

```
for x in results:
    if "January" in datestring:
        x["auction_date"] = datestring.replace("January", "janvier")

    elif "February" in datestring:
        x["auction_date"] = datestring.replace("February", "février")

...
```

If the string is `"31 may - 1 June 2019"`, `"31 mai - 1 June 2019"` is the result.

Comment: change `elif` to `if`

Comment: You could also improve your code by making to lists - month in EN and in FR and find and get rid of ifs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do not do the `elif` part !

```
for x in results:

    if "January" in datestring:
        datestring = datestring.replace("January", "janvier")

    if "February" in datestring:
        datestring = datestring.replace("February", "février")
    # ...
    x["auction_date"] = datestring
```

If you are motivated, you can even do it in oneline :

`datestring.replace("January", "janvier").replace("February", "fevrier") #...` As replace, do not replace if there is no matching strings

As a more readable way :

```
months = [("janvier", "january"), ("fevrier", "february"), ("mars", "march")]

for french_m, english_m in months:
    datestring.replace(english_m, french_m)
```

Comment: there wasn't an `else` part

Comment: Great, now it will only replace `"June"` in the example

Comment: You should use one single list of `(en name, fr name)` tuples instead of two parallel lists.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'll fixed this thanks for pointing out (I thought the lists could be used somewhere else)

Comment: @BlueSheepToken as a general rule, "parallel lists" are a bad idea - what they descibe is semantically a mapping, but the relationship is implicit (the way you use them) instead of explicit (like you would with a proper mapping) and somewhat brittle (sort one of the lists in place and your mapping is broken). Using an explicit mapping (dict or list of tuples) is both more explicit and more robust.  And an explicit mapping doesn't prevent you from "using the lists elsewhere": `en_months = [en for en, fr in months]`

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruno, you are completely right